# Expose GCP resources without exposing console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, identity-management

I’m trying to expose access to a few GCP resources within a project(not all) to an external vendor.

These include a VM(no external IP), private kubernetes cluster and GCS.

Knowing that once the user logs into the VM we can provide access to all required resources via the VM service account.

We essentially need to find a way for the user to access the VM  and only that VM via IAP(as there is no external IP) without letting them log into the console.

The user should not even be able to view other projects VMs in that same project.

What would be the best way to set the IAM policies for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Services accounts cannot access the Google Cloud Console GUI. Provide the vendor with a service account and assign whatever roles you require to the service account.

To use IAP refer to this link:

[Grant permissions to use IAP TCP forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding)

For Compute Engine refer to this link. This gets more complicated depending on the roles you assigned to the VM instance.

[Compute Engine IAM roles and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam)

For absolute security, I would not implement your strategy. Instead, I would implement a bastion host (aka jump host). The vendor is provided with only SSH keys and no IAM permissions to anything - not even IAP. The best solution depends on trust. The more trust control required, the higher the risk and implementation cost.

Comment: Thanks that’s what I was thinking too. Was wondering how I can set service account passwords?

Comment: @VedantShetty - Service accounts do not have passwords. Service accounts are an entire identity using two factors: a) email address; b) RSA private key. Given a service account JSON key file, the only additional item required are IAM roles (permissions) to resources.

Comment: I’m wondering how do I share a service account with a specific vendor? Share the JSON key file?

Comment: @VedantShetty - Yes, provide them with the JSON key file.